# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause in a Linq query using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this here Linq query using lambda expressions and its throwing an error

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Here is the query in question

```
var query = from county in HWC.StateCounties.Where(w => w.StateID == id).Select(s => new CountyList
    {
        CountyID = s.StateCountyID,
        CountyName = s.CountyName
    });
```

I even tried adding a .Tolist() at the end and got the same error.

Why is this happening when I clearly have a select clause?

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in my query, the query should be this instead

```
var query = HWC.StateCounties.Where(w => w.StateID == id).Select(s => new 
        {
            s.StateCountyID,
            s.CountyName
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to combine Linq and extensions methods, a Linq query always needs to end with `select` in c# (In vb this is not necessary).
Maybe it is a matter of taste, but I prefer Linq over extension methods because it makes the code far more readable because all  braces are removed.

Your query will look like

```
var query = 
   from county in HWC.StateCounties
   where county.stateID == id
   select new
   {
       county.StateCountyID,
       county.CountyName,
   };
```

If you want to combine the query will look like:

```
var query = 
   from county in HWC.StateCounties.Where(s => s.stateID == id)
   select new
   {
       county.StateCountyID,
       county.CountyName,
   };
```

Comment: I like to use Linq over extension methods too. But its always good to be able to write in both, you never know when you'll run across a project that prefers one over the other